# Deposit and Withdraw on Account

Tags: python

My code asks the user whether he or she wants to deposit or withdraw an amount from an already entered balance by entering number (5) or number (6) on the menu. I thought my code would work, but when I deposit or withdraw money and enter (1) on the menu to check my balance it gives me the original balance and not the withdrawn or deposited amount. I also thought my Monthly Interest and Interest Rate would work, but they don't. I have written the calculations to get the monthly interest rate, but it doesn't seem to work either when I want to display them.

main module:

```
from Account import Account

id = float(input("Enter User ID: "))
annual_interest_rate = float(input("Enter Interest Rate: "))
balance = float(input("Enter balance: "))

def apply_actions(action, account):
    if action == 0:      # display ID
        print(f"Your id is {id}")
    elif action == 1:    # display balance
        print(f"Your balance is {balance}")
    elif action == 2:     # display annual interest rate
        print(f"Your Annual Interest Rate is {annual_interest_rate}")
    elif action == 3:     # display monthly interest rate
        print(f"Your monthly interest rate is {Account.monthly_interest_rate}")
    elif action == 4:     # display monthly interest
        print(f"Your Monthly Interest is {Account.get_monthly_interest}")
    elif action == 5:     # ask for money to withdraw
        to_withdraw = float(input("How much money do you want to Withdraw?"))
        account.withdraw(to_withdraw)
    elif action == 6:     # ask for money to deposit
        amount = float(input("How much money do you want to deposit?"))
        account.deposit(amount)
    elif action == 7:     # ask to exit
        exit(7)
    else:
        print("Bad index")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    acc = Account(id, balance, annual_interest_rate)

    actions = ["Display ID",
               "Display Balance",
               "Display Annual Interest Rate",
               "Display Monthly Interest Rate",
               "Display Monthly Interest",
               "Withdraw Money",
               "Deposit Money",
               "Exit"]
    while True:
        choice = int(input("Choose index in " + str(list(enumerate(actions)))))
        apply_actions(choice, acc)
```

Account.py

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self, id, balance, annual_interest_rate):
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
        self.annual_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate


    def monthly_interest_rate(self):
        return self.annual_interest_rate / 12

    def id(self):
        return self.id

    def balance(self):
        return self.balance

    def annual_interest_rate(self):
        return self.annual_interest_rate


    def get_monthly_interest(self):
        return self.balance * self.monthly_interest_rate

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance < amount:
            raise ValueError(f"Overdraft, balance less than {amount}")

        self.balance -= amount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance +=amount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that. I made a mistake with regards to calling.

This should fix the errors that pop up.

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self, id, balance, annual_interest_rate):
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
        self.annual_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate


    def monthly_interest_rate(self):
        return self.annual_interest_rate / 12

    def id(self):
        return self.id

    def balance(self):
        return self.balance

    def annual_interest_rate(self):
        return self.annual_interest_rate


    def get_monthly_interest(self):
        # NOTE: You need the () after self.balance to tell Python to use the method and not the variable, or after self.monthtly_interest_rate. Otherwise, Python takes this as a function instead of a value.
        return self.balance() * self.monthly_interest_rate

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance < amount:
            raise ValueError(f"Overdraft, balance less than {amount}")

        self.balance -= amount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance +=amount

id = float(input("Enter User ID: "))
annual_interest_rate = float(input("Enter Interest Rate: "))
balance = float(input("Enter balance: "))

def apply_actions(action, account):
    if action == 0:      # display ID
        print(f"Your id is {account.id}")
    elif action == 1:    # display balance
        print(f"Your balance is {account.balance}")
    elif action == 2:     # display annual interest rate
        print(f"Your Annual Interest Rate is {account.annual_interest_rate}")
    elif action == 3:     # display monthly interest rate
        print(f"Your monthly interest rate is {account.monthly_interest_rate()}")
    elif action == 4:     # display monthly interest
        print(f"Your Monthly Interest is {account.get_monthly_interest()}")
    elif action == 5:     # ask for money to withdraw
        to_withdraw = float(input("How much money do you want to Withdraw?"))
        account.withdraw(to_withdraw)
    elif action == 6:     # ask for money to deposit
        amount = float(input("How much money do you want to deposit?"))
        account.deposit(amount)
    elif action == 7:     # ask to exit
        exit(7)
    else:
        print("Bad index")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    acc = Account(id, balance, annual_interest_rate)

    actions = ["Display ID",
               "Display Balance",
               "Display Annual Interest Rate",
               "Display Monthly Interest Rate",
               "Display Monthly Interest",
               "Withdraw Money",
               "Deposit Money",
               "Exit"]
    while True:
        choice = int(input("Choose index in " + str(list(enumerate(actions)))))
        apply_actions(choice, acc)
```

Comment: is right, you have two "balance" variables, one in the global scope and one inside your class and of course inside the object of that class, so what you do is change the global and read the one inside the account

Comment: Your code is giving me many errors. I now cannot display the balance, id, or interest rate entered at the beginning of the program. It is giving me "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable".

Comment: Why, when I call to display ID, it doesn't when I have defined id on my Account.py module?

Comment: User3230: I think that there is a clash between the `id` field and the `id` method?

Comment: Yes, @phalanx is right: the problem is that you have variables and methods with the same name in `Account`, and Python doesn't know when you make a call like `account.id` if you're referring to the variable `id` or the method `id`. If you write `account.id()` then the parentheses clarify that the call is to the method.